# How to clear input stream that received multiple inputs in c?

Tags: input, stream, buffer, fflush

I am writing a client-server project using TCP protocol, so in my client code I have a while loop with a read() in it that waits for a write() from the server.

I think that this is irrelevant to the question I'm actually asking, however, this is what causes my problem which is that while the client is waiting for a write() from the server, the user can type sentences on the terminal that get stacked on the input buffer, so when my client finally receives a write() and moves on from his read(), I can't clear the input buffer with the usual way of clearing every character until the new line character is found:

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

because the user has typed many sentences and pressed enter multiple times while he was waiting.

Is there any way that I can fully clear the input stream no matter what is in it?

All I found out so far is that I can use `fflush(stdin)` and, although unconventional, it works for me, but sometimes it doesn't so I can't use it.

I also tried checking the input stream's end with:

```
while (getchar() != '\0');
```

But it gets stuck in an infinite loop. I also tried using a scanf() that ignores new lines after read():

```
scanf("%[^\r\t\n]s", buf);
```

so that everything would get moved to this buffer, this didn't work either, only the first word from the last sentence typed gets stored there.

Lastly, I tried messing around with fgets() but no luck there either.

P.S. Is there any way I can completely disable the standard input stream before the read() call and enable it again right after?

**Edit**: For archive purposes, I actually forked my program at this point as to continue scaning inputs and instantly clearing them with the standard first way I mentioned. Still, I would like to know if there is a way to completely clear the input buffer no matter what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems promising: 
Basically what he/she is doing is using fgets with fflush..

https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/217396/how-to-properly-flush-the-input-stream-stdin